# Возможно ли использование паттерна в моем случае?

Tags: node.js

Имеется `socket.io server` и класс `Random`

```
class Random {
    constructor(timer) {
        this.timer = timer
        this.status = 0
    }
    async setStatus() {
        const interval = setInterval(()=> {
            this.timer -= 1
            if(this.timer <= 0) {
                this.status = 1
            }
        }, 1000)
    }

}
```

Код `Socket.io server`

```
const Random = require('../Random').Random
const chanels = {}
const timers = [{timer: 20, name: "chanel1"},{timer: 400, "chanel2"}]
timers.map((timer,id) => chanels[timer.name] = new Random(timer.time))

socket.on('startTimer', async (name, callback) => {
    await chanels[name].setStatus()
})
```

Проблема:

Я хочу выполнять определенное событие на `socket`-сервере в том случае, если `this.status = 1`. Т.е мне нужно отслеживать смену `this.status` и оповещать об этом socket часть

Вопрос:

Каким образом это можно реализовать? Пытался сделать через `setInterval` на стороне сокета запрашивая каждую секунду `this.state`, но на мой взгляд это крайне плохое решение. Наткнулся на паттерн `observer`, но возможна ли его реализация в моем случае?

Answer (score 0):

Random.js

```
class Random {
  constructor(timer) {
    this.timer = timer
    this.status = 0
  }
  async setStatus() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      if (status === 1) {
        resolve(this);
      }
      setTimeout(
        () => {
          this.status = 1;
          resolve(this);
        },
        this.timer * 1000
      );
    });
  }
}

module.exports = { Random };
```

обработчик socket-событий:

```
const Random = require('../Random').Random

const channelSettings = [
  { delay: 20, name: "channel1" },
  { delay: 400, name: "channel2" },
];

const channels = channelSettings.reduce((acc, {delay, name}) => {
  acc[name] = new Random(delay);
  return acc;
}, {});

socket.on('startTimer', async (name, callback) => {
  if (name in channels) {
    await channels[name].setStatus();
    //
    // do something here...
    //
  }
});
```